# C - How to take string as arguments

Tags: c, arrays, string, arguments

I have this code that will take user input and do something with it.

```
int main ()
{
    char key[] = "quit";
    char buffer[80];
    do {
        printf ("CMD> ");
        scanf ("%s",buffer);
    } while (strcmp (key,buffer) != 0);
    printf ("Bye.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to integrate other commands.
So of I ask a user to input a command like a string:

```
CMD > xxx -a 32
```

And he gives me a string "xxx -a 32". How can I take them as arguments?

So I can use case to call a functions with those arguments like:

```
switch(xxx) {  // first arg

   case (-a)  :  // second arg
      callAFunction(32);  // third arg 
      break;
}
```

Comment: You cannot give variable name at run time . The variable in `switch` has to be declared in program and what you can do it take its value at run time .

Answer (score 0):

As ameyCU pointed out, you cannot use `switch` that way because you need to have the variable name to use with `switch` at compile time. However, you can use `strcmp` to compare the string argument (`xxx`) that user enters at run time.

To split user input into multiple arguments, you can try `strtok`, something along this line (this assume enters exactly three arguments, and there is no error checking yet).

```
    printf ("CMD> ");
    // scanf ("%s",buffer);   // better use fgets
    fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), stdin );

    char *args[3] = { NULL };
    char *pch;

    pch = strtok (buffer," ");
    int i = 0;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        args[i++] = pch;
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        if( args[i] != NULL )
        {
            printf( "args[%d] = %s\n", i, args[i] );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing the following format:
scanf("%s %c %d",arg1,&arg2,&arg3);
But here also you are not done in arg1 the string is stored which is not a variable so you can not put it as a argument to switch command. Try to use arg1 for this purpose

Comment: Providing a sample of correct code would be helpful for the questioner.